# How to reconfigure Geary in Freya?

Tags: pantheon-mail

The problem is that Geary does not start, in the Dock it show a notification, but no start and i need to reconfigurate this package to restart the application, any idea? The version of Geary is 0.10.0

El problema es que Geary no se inicia, en el Dock muestra una notificación, pero no inicia y necesito reconfigurar este paquete para reiniciar la aplicación, ¿alguna idea? La versión de Geary es la 0.10.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero quizás deberías actualizar a Loki, Trusty tiene soporte pero no sé si el resto de componentes de Freya lo tenga aún.

Aparte de eso, puedes ejecutar Geary desde una terminal y revisar si aparece algún mensaje de error. También puedes probar abrirlo desde la sesión de invitados: si tampoco inicia, prueba reinstalándolo desde una terminal con `sudo apt-get install --reinstall geary`; si arranca normal, prueba eliminar las carpetas donde guarda la configuración (`~/.config/geary` y `~/.local/share/geary`).